# Xcode not stopping on breakpoint

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I have some weird problem with Xcode since I upgraded my Xcode to 5 from 4.6. When I set the breakpoint in a file, the program actually stops at the breakpoint, but I can't see my code in the workspace. It loads some other system codes like

```
 0x2ff8:  calll  0x2ffd  -[ViewController viewDidLoad] + 13 at ViewController.m:28
0x2ffd:  popl   %eax
0x2ffe:  movl   12(%ebp), %ecx
0x3001:  movl   8(%ebp), %edx
0x3004:  movl   %edx, -12(%ebp)
0x3007:  movl   %ecx, -16(%ebp)
0x300a:  movl   18799(%eax), %ecx
0x3010:  movl   18559(%eax), %edx
```

[image]

When I click the continue button it shows my code again.
I have tried,

- Creating a new project
- Relaunching Xcode
- Restarting the system
- Re-installing Xcode

None of these helped me. I have seen a lot of questions in StackOverflow which discuss "Breakpoints not working...", but for me the breakpoints are working, just not stopping in the correct position.

Comment: Are you sure it's just not crashing before it reaches your breakpoint?

Comment: It's not crashing(neither xcode nor my app), but I can see something in the workspace which will be shown when an app crashed. And when I hit continue it just runs fine.

Comment: Press the up-arrow button and see where you end up.

Comment: (But, on second glance, it looks like the debugger can't find your source.  Did you use an "odd" build process?  Have you tried to "clean" your build?)

Comment: @Hot Licks: Nope, I found the problem and I've answered below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the problem, Somehow the "Show Disassembly when debugging" was enabled in my Xcode which creates that problem. When I disabled it, all my debugger stopped in my source code.

You can find it under **Product->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly when debugging**

**Edit**

In the latest Xcode it is under **Debug->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly when debugging**

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Debug->Debug Workflow->Show Disassembly when debugging`? I found it under Debug instead of Product (great find nevertheless!).

Comment: Big help, searched a lot for this solution.

Answer (score 4):

Xcode 6:

Go to **Build Settings** and make sure your "**Strip style**" is set up as "**Non-Global Symbols**" and not as "**All Symbols**"

[image]

Comment: This change works for me.. Thanks alot