# Break Point is not working in Xcode7.3

Tags: ios, xcode, backbase-portal, backbase

I started work on a project written in ObjectiveC++ (.mm file extensions) with [backbase](https://my.backbase.com/home) on Xcode 7.3. During work I found that break point is not working in the app. I have reset the settings but still no success. I have also gone through below but still running in same issue

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057684/breakpoints-not-being-hit-in-xcode-7) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64790/why-arent-my-breakpoints-working) [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848684/xcode-not-stopping-on-breakpoint)

Can any help me in resolving this issue? Any idea or suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Breakpoints are working with Obj-C++ code for me. Just check that you are running program with "Debug" command and signing app with developer (not distribution) certificate and provisioning profile (not for App Store)

Comment: thanks.. Should I run the app in actual device? Currently I was trying to debug on Simulator.

Comment: no, you can perfectly debug on simulator